# Apply value into cURL on PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have a question about curl.
Here is the value which will be changed by the user input.

```
$uid = "xxxxx" //Get from system
$token = "xxxxx" //Get from system
$title = "Testing Message"; //user input
$body = "Message"; //user input
$url_on_click = "https://www.xxxxx.com"; //user input
```

I want to apply the value into the function but it getting error:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://bn.xxxxxx.com/wpn/wpn_send',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
                            "uid" :' . $record_uid . ',
                            "payload": ' . $payload . '
                          }',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'token: ' . $record_token . ',
        Content-Type: application/json'
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
return $response;
```

If I change all the value to string. It's work. The follow code like :

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://bn.xxxxxx.com/wpn/wpn_send',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{"uid" :"xxxxxx",
"payload": {
"title": "Testing Message",
"body": "1234",
"icon":"https://xxxxx.net/xxxxx.png",
"urlOnClick":"xxxxx.com"
}}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'token: xxxxxx',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

May I know which part I did wrong? That issue really pull my hair out.
Thank you =]

Comment: That's because your JSON is invalid (missing quotes). Use [`json_encode()`](https://php.net/json_encode) instead of creating it yourself.

Comment: `but it getting error` ~ what is the error? As @Syscall already suggested ~ it's likely a JSON encoding error but would be nice if you included the error message?!

Comment: @Syscall Ya, the json_encode() is not correct because it return a string with "\". I use json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) to send the correct data to the API. Thanks =]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, post fields depend on your `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`, according to your header you need to convert it in `JSON` otherwise, the `array` type will work

```
$postFields = array(
            'uid' => "xxxx",
            'token' => "xxxx",
            'title' => "xxxx",
            'body' => "xxxx",
            'url_on_click' => "xxxx"
        );
//curl init lines
//-------
//-------
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postFields),
```